# Removing a node from a doubly linked list?

Tags: java

Here's the linked list code

```
public class LList
{
protected int size;
protected DNode tail, header; 

public LList()
{
    size = 0;
    tail = null;
    header = tail;
}

public void addDNode(DNode v) 
{
    // means list is empty, so add first element
    if (header == null) 
    {    
        header = v;
        tail = header;  // first element so (head == tail)
    } 
    else 
    {
        tail.setNext(v);
        v.setPrev(tail);
        v.setNext(null);
        tail = v;
    }
    size++;
}
```

and the remove node method that's the problem

```
public DNode removeDnode(DNode current)
{
    if(current.nextNode() ==  null)
    {
        DNode previous = current.prevNode();
        previous.setNext(null);
        current.setPrev(null);
    }
    else if (current.prevNode() == null)
    {
        DNode next = current.nextNode();
        next.setPrev(null);
        current.setNext(null);
    }
    else
    {
        DNode next = current.nextNode();
        DNode previous = current.prevNode();
        previous.setNext(next);
        next.setPrev(previous);
        current.setPrev(null);
        current.setNext(null);
    }
    size = size - 1;
    return current;
}
```

The problem is that when I use previous.setNext(null); it won't let me add a node again which I think it has something to do with the header and tail.

however when i use previous.setNext(tail); it doesn't seem to remove it from the list??

Comment: It looks as though your first two `if` blocks in your `remove` method are for `LinkedList`s that do not have headers/tails. The whole point of having headers and tails is so you can treat every node in the list the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, if you remove `tail`, you must move it. So try

```
    DNode previous = current.prevNode();
    previous.setNext(null);
    current.setPrev(null);
    tail = previous;
```

You have the same problem with the `next`—but I believe once you're done with `tail`, you'll fix it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you forgetting to point the tail of the list to the previous element when you remove the last?

```
if(current.nextNode() ==  null) {
    DNode previous = current.prevNode();
    previous.setNext(null);
    current.setPrev(null);
    tail = previous; //isn't this missing?!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling remove from a doubly-linked list is *VERY* tricky.  When you see a bug while testing, don't just make a "quick fix" -- go back and understand precisely why it didn't work, and understand how your intended fix will modify *all* behaviors, not simply the one that's currently misbehaving.

If you think about it carefully you can make it work with a minimum of problems.  If you don't think carefully you'll be chasing your tail for hours.